# How to build raster file from large folder tiles (256x256), which has 70.000 file tiles

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, large-datasets

First, I'd like to mention that I'm new to working with GIS, so please forgive my inexperience.

I have map folder with structure: zoom level contains multi tile image files (256x256),ex: folder zoom 12-> 81 tiles, 13 -> 306 tiles ... zoom 17 -> 77235 tiles.
[image]

By using LEAFLET I can display map as below
[image]

My tile map name indexs start from 0_0 (x_y), not follow coordinates EPSG-3857. Now I want to integrate google map layer with this map, I must convert all tile map images to new coordinate. So I decide to use QGIS with GeoReferencer to convert, but I am stuck in a problem: when I merged all tile map images at zoom level 17 to create tiff image then load it to QGIS, the result flat image too large with dimension 9.000.000 x 9.000.000 pixels, my computer was frozen. Even, I try with lower zoom 16, the image also too large to handle in QGIS.

I have checked GEOTiff format with metadata structure but I'm not sure about this format can help
So I wonder if QGIS supports other formats, which no need to merge all tile images to a large flat image, does anyone know of a good method/set of tools to handle my issue?